# Customize bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Hi I am trying to customize the boostrap default navbar.

I do not expect you to do all my work, but I need help to style the li field so it hangs over the navbar.

How do I make that?

**Code I have:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavigation-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" href="#">Caleum Wellness</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavigation-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Behandlingar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tidsbokning</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blogg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The first image show how it is now, and the second image is how I want it.

[image: This is what i have now]

[image: This is how i want it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by creating a background image with height lower than the navigation wrapper.

The wrapper is still the same size but it looks like it is smaller.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Bootstrap customizer http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Just change less variables how you want and then download it.

Comment: It would be great if it were that simple, well i have the less in my source code so no need for download.

The question is still, what shall i change to make the li float over the nav.navbar class.